# Caliburn Micro not support cal:View.Context at design-time?

Tags: caliburn.micro, design-time, viewcontext

Create window:

```
<Window
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyType, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
  cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">

    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Model}" cal:View.Context="ViewContext1"/>

</Window>
```

Create view for view-model named `[Root namespace].Model.ViewContext1`.

At design time see *"Can't find view for view-model"*.

When run - is all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Caliburn.Micro in ViewModel first approach, and binding contextual content inside a view to same model (initial ViewModel), make sure to set View.Context before setting View.Model.

You will want to swap them around in this case like so:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Context="ViewContext1" cal:View.Model="{Binding Model}" />
```